# NbChatComponent component load messages on scroll

Tags: javascript, angular, chat, nebular

I am using nebular chat component in angular

```
<nb-chat
  #chatComponent
  [scrollBottom]="true"
  class="search-results"
  infinite-scroll
  [infiniteScrollDistance]="scrollDistance"
  [infiniteScrollUpDistance]="scrollUpDistance"
  [infiniteScrollThrottle]="throttle"
  (scrolled)="loadNext()"
  (scrolledUp)="loadNext()"
>
  <nb-chat-message
    *ngFor="let msg of messages"
    [type]="msg.type"
    [message]="msg.text"
    [reply]="msg.reply"
    [sender]="msg.user.name"
    [date]="msg.date"
    [dateFormat]="'h:mm a'"
    [files]="msg.files"
  >
  </nb-chat-message>

  <nb-chat-form
    (send)="sendMessage($event)"
    [dropFiles]="false"
    [attr.automation-id]="'chat_box_send_message'"
  >
  </nb-chat-form>
</nb-chat>
```

I wawnt to load messages based on scroll up.
I have used ngx-infinite-scroll package but it does not detect the scroll event

I have used multiple components to scorll like ngx-infinite-scroll and NbInfiniteListDirective as well. but on scrolling the messages the scroll event is not getting triggred.